# Datatable passed to sub not interating through rows properly

Tags: vb.net, datatable

So here's the deal - I've been working on this PTO Program for my company for about a month or so now.  I'm doing final QA and came across an issue I didn't see in my previous testing.

So once a manager logs into the application they go to a screen to approve PTO.  They can select multiple lines in the datagridview and click approve and those records get updated on the DB side - it records the person who approved as well as the time and date and updates a boolean for approval status.  All of that works as intended.

The issue is when I get to emailing the user that the PTO has been approved.  As part of the SQL update command the application makes a datatable and adds Name, email, PTO Date, PTO Type, Hours and User ID to that table for each PTO day approved.  I push that table over to my email sub and it all goes haywire.  It sends the email to each user who had approved PTO but each person gets the same PTO Details - even though I know the datatable I pass over has the correct data for each user.

See below for the code - what am I missing here?  Thanks for the help - this is my largest issue left and this thing is almost ready to deploy!

Edit to add: I think the issue lies in where i make the PTORows datarow, I think it's always selecting the first row in the approvalemaillist datatable and filling it.

```
Public Sub sendEmail(approvalEmailList As DataTable)

    Dim linecount As Integer = 0
    Dim hours As New Integer
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim ptoType As New List(Of String)
    Dim itercount As Integer = 0
    Dim spottype As Integer = 0
    Dim makecount As Integer = 0

    Dim email = From row In approvalEmailList.AsEnumerable()
                Select row.Field(Of String)("Email") Distinct

    'For Each str As String In email
    For Each row As DataRow In approvalEmailList.Rows

        sb.Clear()

        'Reset Linecount for new email
        linecount = 0

        sb.AppendLine("PTO Request Approved")
        sb.AppendLine("")
        sb.AppendLine("PTO Request Details:")
        sb.AppendLine("")
        sb.AppendLine("PTO Request Approval Date: " & DateTime.Today)

        Dim PTORows() As DataRow = approvalEmailList.Select("Email = '" & email(linecount).ToString & "'", "PTODate Desc")

        Dim PTODate As Date = Nothing

        For Each pto As DataRow In PTORows
            PTODate = PTORows(linecount).ItemArray(2).ToString
            If PTORows(linecount).ItemArray(4).ToString = True Then
                hours = 4
            Else
                hours = 8
            End If
            sb.AppendLine("PTO Date: " & PTODate.ToShortDateString & " - PTO Type: " & PTORows(linecount).ItemArray(3).ToString & " - Hours: " & hours.ToString)
            linecount += 1
        Next

        'makemath(PTORows(0).ItemArray(5).ToString)

        'makecount += 1

        sb.AppendLine("")
        'sb.AppendLine("PTO Balances after approval:")
        'sb.AppendLine("")
        'sb.AppendLine("PTO Balance: " & PTOBal.ToString)
        'sb.AppendLine("Personal Day Balance: " & Personal.ToString)
        'sb.AppendLine("Floating Holiday Balance: " & Float.ToString)

        Dim OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Dim OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = email(linecount).ToString 'str.ToString
            .CC = MainForm.GlobalVariables.currentADUser.EmailAddress
            .Subject = "PTO Approved"
            .body = sb.ToString()
            .send
        End With

    Next

    Dim mgsRslt As MsgBoxResult = MessageBox.Show("PTO Request approved - email(s) successfully sent!",
        "Success",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Information,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)

    If mgsRslt = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
        Me.Controls.Clear() 'removes all the controls on the form
        InitializeComponent() 'load all the controls again
        MgrApprove_Load() 'Load everything in your form load event again
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: are you sending this string to an SQL server in a production environment?  Dim PTORows() As DataRow = approvalEmailList.Select("Email = '" & email(linecount).ToString & "'", "PTODate Desc") If you actually do that I would suggest you change your approach to parameters in SQL to avoid injection attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a couple changes:

Loop through your distinct list of e-mails (which you have commented out):

```
 For Each str As String In email
```

Then, the selection should be this because you only want parent table records matching the e-mail address.

```
Dim PTORows() As DataRow = approvalEmailList.Select("Email = '" & str & "'", "PTODate Desc")
```

In the sub-loop, reference your row just as row

```
For Each pto As DataRow In PTORows
        PTODate = pto.ItemArray(2).ToString
        If pto.ItemArray(4).ToString = True Then
            hours = 4
        Else
            hours = 8
        End If
        sb.AppendLine("PTO Date: " & PTODate.ToShortDateString & " - PTO Type: " & pto.ItemArray(3).ToString & " - Hours: " & hours.ToString)
        linecount += 1
Next
```